# Connecting Spring boot application with postgresql problem with properties

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, properties

I wanted to connect my application from spring boot with postgresql running in docker
I am doing everything according to this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fbfHu8isI4&t=1452s , but I keep getting the same error:

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-08-02 16:18:56.400 ERROR 4169 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Process finished with exit code 1

This is connecting with database

PostgresDataSource:

```
 package com.example.restservice.datasource;

  import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
  import 
  org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

public class PostgresDataSource {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource hikariDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }
}
```

in application.yml

```
app:
  datasource:
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/drmdb
    username: postgres
    password: password
    pool-size: 30
```

I have these problems in application.yml and I have no idea what is wrong

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZumWB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in this line:

```
jdbcUrl: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/drmdb
```

You should fix it to:

```
jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/drmdb
```

When using the guides, always look at the description. Sometimes there is a source code.

[Guider application.yml file](https://github.com/amigoscode/spring-boot-react-fullstack/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml)

As @grekier stated you should also add `@Configuration` to `PostgresDatasource` class.

[Guider Datasource file](https://github.com/amigoscode/spring-boot-react-fullstack/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amigoscode/demo/datasource/Datasource.java)

Answer (score 0):

I think you also are missing an `@Configuration` on the `PostgresDatasource` class